# Software solution for mono speakers in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

I've found many questions about this issue, but people would find a solution that I wouldn't find or they would solve the issue in a hardware way. For me, these are not an option so I've decided to ask a question of my own.

My problem is that my left speaker is broken as well as my right earphone so there's no way to have all of the sound. In music, there's always some instruments missing. Balance doesn't fix this problem. In Windows XP, the balance would create a mono sound because it's a one slider and that would fix my problem, but Windows 7 has two sliders and I have Windows 7. I put the left speaker to minimum and right to maximum and vice versa and there's either only right speaker sound or no sound at all. I'm a musician and this really annoys me and has also been giving me headaches.

Is there a free full DRM-less virus-less software hack where the stereo sound is put into a mono sound so that the right speaker gets both right and left channel?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/117494/force-windows-to-output-only-mono-sound

Answer (score 2):

This software can do it.

http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/index.htm#DownloadVoicemeeter

[image]

Choose your output device at first arrow and set up mono at second.

[Copied From Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1038832/40928)

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I checked into this, and as far as I could find out Windows 7 does not have a system-based mono output ability.

However some video players may allow mixed audio output as mono. I use [MPC-HC](https://mpc-hc.org), which may work depending on what your audio source is.